# Chrome App: When I run cca create I get: Cannot find module 'delayed-stream'

Tags: google-chrome-app

I am following the guide here https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps/blob/master/docs/Installation.md to create a Chrome App that runs on Android. I have everything set up correctly on a Windows 7 machine I think. I can run the `cca checkenv` and this works fine. But when I go to actually creating the app I get

```
C:\Users\wilblack\Projects>cca create TestApp --copy-from=C:\Users\wilblack\Projects\chromeapp_demo\manifest.json
cca v0.0.3
## Checking that tools are installed
Android SDK detected.
Searching for Chrome app source in C:\Users\wilblack\Projects\chromeapp_demo
## Creating Your Application
create TestApp Hello World! Hello World!
Writing config.xml
Changing directory to: C:\Users\wilblack\Projects\TestApp 
platform add android
plugin add org.apache.cordova.file
Error: Fetching plugin failed: Error: Cannot find module 'delayed-stream'
```

I think it has something to do with Node.js but I am not sure. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Correction to another answer- it's "delayed-stream", not "direct-stream", so the magic command line instruction is:

```
npm install -g delayed-stream
```

Then retry cca create. Worked for me...

Answer (score 1):

Install the direct-stream module globally:

`npm install -g direct-stream`

Create your project:

`cca create yourprojectname`

It should now be created successfully. I had the same problem yesterday. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

We hope this problem to be fixed in the cca@0.0.4 release (now live).